# derivative of the functions in Hadamard's lemma

Tags: distribution-theory

I think **Corollary 1.10** of [this PDF](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/31371/mod_resource/content/1/b43ln.pdf) page 12 is [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma)
[image]
here $\partial_jf$ is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ and $\alpha$ is a multi-index. $\partial^\alpha$ is defined by
$$\partial^\alpha u(x):=\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} u}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}(x)$$
The proof of **Corollary 1.10** (on the next page) defines the functions
$$f_j(x)=\int_0^1\left(\partial_j f\right)\left(x_0+t\left(x-x_0\right)\right) \mathrm{d} t$$
It says *The assertions about $f_j$ all follow by inspection.*
I don't know how to deduce one of the assertions:
$$\partial^\alpha f_j\left(x_0\right)=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
where does the factor $1/(1+|α|)$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugging in $f_j$ we need to prove: [At this point we cannot replace $x$ with $x_0$ in the integral, because the integral has $\partial^\alpha$ in front of it, we need to evaluate the derivative of a function of $x$ at $x=x_0$, if we had replaced $x$ with $x_0$ in the integral, then it would be the derivative of a constant.]
$$\partial^\alpha \int_0^1(\partial_j f)\left(x_0+t\left(x-x_0\right)\right) \mathrm{d} t\Bigg|_{x=x_0}=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
Interchanging $\partial^\alpha \int_0^1$
$$\int_0^1\partial^\alpha\Bigl((\partial_j f)\left(x_0+t\left(x-x_0\right)\right)\Bigr)\mathrm{d} t\Bigg|_{x=x_0}=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
Applying chain rule
$$\int_0^1t^{|\alpha|}(\partial^\alpha\partial_j f)\left(x_0+t\left(x-x_0\right)\right)\mathrm{d} t\Bigg|_{x=x_0}=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
Replacing $x$ with $x_0$ in the integral
$$\int_0^1t^{|\alpha|}(\partial^\alpha\partial_j f)\left(x_0+t\left(x_0-x_0\right)\right)\mathrm{d} t=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
Canceling $x_0-x_0$
$$\int_0^1t^{|\alpha|}(\partial^\alpha\partial_j f)\left(x_0\right)\mathrm{d} t=\partial^\alpha \partial_j f\left(x_0\right) /(1+|\alpha|)$$
Note that $(\partial^\alpha\partial_j f)\left(x_0\right)$ in the integral is constant wrt $t$, and $\int_0^1t^{|\alpha|}\mathrm dt=\frac1{1+|\alpha|}$, we are done.